# Can Rope auto-completion (RopeCodeAssist) in vim not automatically insert results?

Tags: python, vim, autocomplete, rope

I am using Rope for my python auto-completion in vim. However, one thing that annoys me is that it auto-inserts its suggestions, making me unable to narrow down choices by continuing to type. This means that if I see my desired completion at the bottom of the list, I must move through the entire list with the down-arrow-key to select it.

My preferred usage would be seeing the list of suggested completions and be able to continue typing, which automatically removes items from the list that don't begin with my typed characters. An extra bonus would be the ability to then move down the list with the tab key.

In short, I would like the completion selection process to be like vim's omnicompletion when the options `completeopt=longest,menu,menuone` are set. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

[python-mode](https://github.com/klen/python-mode) sets Vim's `omnifunc` to use Rope completion, which should do what you want.

Otherwise, you could check out [this rope-omni plugin](https://github.com/rygwdn/rope-omni).

Answer (score 0):

`rope-omni` plugin has been merged into the standard `ropevim` in [this commit](https://github.com/python-rope/ropevim/commit/255dac5dc4ec04375279a0c6c85c4f879502bbc6). And yes, https://github.com/python-rope/ is now the official home of all rope projects.